# fraction of a week from a date in R

Tags: r, date, week-number

I'm trying to get the fraction of the week from a dd/mm/yyyy.  I start with a data frame the looks like

```
mydate<-as.factor(c("22/12/2010","19/03/2012","16/02/2013"))
```

this is an example. in reality thousands of dates are brought is as csv file, hence the 'as.factor` to show how the data originates.

```
mydate<-as.Date(mydate,format="%d/%m/%Y") #[1] "2010-12-22" "2012-03-18" "2013-02-16"

myweek<-as.numeric(strftime(mydate,format="%U"))
```

Help says that %U should be week of the year as a decimal number

This gives `[1] 51 12  6`

What I am looking for is

```
50.71, 11.14, 6.57
```

I've tried setting the `decimal=2` in various locations, and have tried `as.POSIXct`/`as.POSIXlt` in various locations and combinations in the script with no joy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this where `mydate` is of `"Date"` class:

```
> round((as.numeric(format(mydate, "%j")) - 1) / 7, 2)
[1] 50.71 11.14  6.57
```

Omit the `round` part if you want more than 2 digits.